# Animation Arrays not animating sprite

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am making a simple RPG in Swift with SpriteKit. I wrote a character class to help me handle all the animations and I am having some trouble with the animation.

Character class:

```
class Character: SKSpriteNode {

    var walkSouthArray = [SKTexture]()
    var walkNorthArray = [SKTexture]()
    var walkEastArray = [SKTexture]()
    var walkWestArray = [SKTexture]()

    override init(texture: SKTexture?, color: UIColor, size: CGSize) {
        super.init(texture: nil, color: UIColor.clear, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 150))
        self = CGSize(width: 100, height: 150)
        self.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        self.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "walk_south_1")

        let northAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "walk_north")
        var northFrames:[SKTexture] = []
        for index in 1 ... 8 {
            let textureName = "walk_north_\(index)"
            let texture = northAtlas.textureNamed(textureName)
            northFrames.append(texture)
            walkNorthArray = northFrames
        }

        let southAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "walk_south")
        var southFrames:[SKTexture] = []
        for index in 1 ... 8 {
            let textureName = "walk_south_\(index)"
            let texture = southAtlas.textureNamed(textureName)
            southFrames.append(texture)
            walkSouthArray = southFrames
        }

        let eastAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "walk_east")
        var eastFrames:[SKTexture] = []
        for index in 1 ... 8 {
            let textureName = "walk_east_\(index)"
            let texture = eastAtlas.textureNamed(textureName)
            eastFrames.append(texture)
            walkEastArray = eastFrames
        }

        let westAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "walk_west")
        var westFrames:[SKTexture] = []
        for index in 1 ... 8 {
            let textureName = "walk_\(index)"
            let texture = westAtlas.textureNamed(textureName)
            westFrames.append(texture)
            walkWestArray = westFrames
        }


    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func walkNorth() {
        self.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.animate(with: walkNorthArray, timePerFrame: 0.2)))
    }

    func walkSouth() {
        self.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.animate(with: walkSouthArray, timePerFrame: 0.2)))
    }

    func walkEast() {
        self.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.animate(with: walkEastArray, timePerFrame: 0.2)))
    }

    func walkWest() {
        self.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.animate(with: walkWestArray, timePerFrame: 0.2)))
    }
}
```

*the frames for Walk West haven't been drawn yet*

Game Scene class:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    var v = CGVector()

    var xJoystickDelta = CGFloat()
    var yJoystickDelta = CGFloat()

    var UINode = SKNode()
    var WorldNode = SKNode()

    var character = Character()

    var DPad = SKSpriteNode()
    var thumbNode = SKSpriteNode()

    var isTracking:Bool = false

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        DPad = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "base"))
        DPad.size = CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)
        DPad.position = CGPoint(x: -200, y: -100)
        DPad.zPosition = 3
        UINode.addChild(DPad)

        thumbNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "stick"))
        thumbNode.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
        thumbNode.position = CGPoint(x: -200, y: -100)
        thumbNode.zPosition = 4
        UINode.addChild(thumbNode)

        self.addChild(UINode)
        self.addChild(character)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            if isTracking == false && DPad.contains(location) {
                isTracking = true
            }
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            let location: CGPoint = touch.location(in: self)
            if isTracking == true {

                v = CGVector(dx: location.x - DPad.position.x, dy: location.y - DPad.position.y)
                let angle = atan2(v.dy, v.dx)
                let deg = angle * CGFloat(180 / Double.pi)

                let Length:CGFloat = DPad.frame.size.height / 2
                let xDist: CGFloat = sin(angle - 1.57079633) * Length
                let yDist: CGFloat = cos(angle - 1.57079633) * Length

                xJoystickDelta = location.x - DPad.position.x
                yJoystickDelta = location.y - DPad.position.y

                if DPad.contains(location) {
                    thumbNode.position = location
                } else {
                    thumbNode.position = CGPoint(x: DPad.position.x - xDist, y: DPad.position.y + yDist)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        isTracking = false
        thumbNode.run(SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: -200, y: -100), duration: 0.01))
        xJoystickDelta = 0
        yJoystickDelta = 0
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        // Called before each frame is rendered
        if v.dx > abs(v.dy) {
            // right
            character.walkEast()
        } else if v.dx < -abs(v.dy) {
            // left
            character.walkWest()
        } else if v.dy > 0 {
            // up
            character.walkNorth()
        } else if v.dy < 0 {
            // down
            character.walkSouth()
        }
    }
}
```

Its set up in such a way so that all I have to do is call the functions for the animations. When I call them all I get is a single still image (the first image in the Atlas)

My atlases are set up correctly as far as I know:

[image: Image 1]

I clicked the "+" button and selected "New Sprite Atlas" then dragged/dropped my images into the new folder and renamed it.

Comment: do `print("Am I paused? \(player.isPaused)")` in your update loop and tell me if he is paused or not

Comment: Just did what you said, not paused. Let me edit in the part where I am calling the functions.

Comment: wait a minute,  you are doing a node in a node..  remove "player" and just make your "Character" extend SKSpritenode to avoid the confusion, otherwise you may need to check if the character instance is also paused

Comment: I switched the class over to an SKSpriteNode instead of an SKNode. Still getting the same error.

Comment: did you also remove the player variable and make it self instead?

Comment: Yeah, all of it has been stripped out and switched over to `self` instead.

Comment: Do you think this is possibly a bug?

Comment: Yes, on your end lol

Comment: I think it may be a bug because I can call `self.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.animate(with: walkNorthArray, timePerFrame: 0.2)))` inside the `super.init` scope and it will animate with the selected atlas perfectly. When I call the action outside the scope it won't work. I tried moving the snippet that sets up the animation into the animation function and it also will not work.

Comment: Yes, that means the bug is on your end.  You proved to yourself apples function works, you are just using it in an incorrect manner

Comment: I'm confused, what do you mean by "you are just using it in an incorrect manner"? Is my code written wrong? Can you see any errors with my setup? If so, how do I fix it?

Comment: I need more code to truly understand why it is failing,  maybe you can send me your project and I will play with it later on tonight to explain the error.

Comment: I'll add my GameScene.swift. That is basically the entire project so far, its still relatively new.

Comment: Added GameScene.swift above.

Comment: You are calling the animation every update

Comment: ‍♂️ I never would have figured that out.... Thanks, I'll move it to touches moved and put things in place to make sure that it only gets called once every time it changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always be careful when doing things in your update cycle.

This operation runs at 60 FPS be default for most devices, so any command inside of it will fire at that rate.

In your particular situation,  you were adding a new animation action every update, so as for as the application is concerned, it is drawing the animation, but you keep on adding a new starting animation to the mix.

Since you do not have "X-Ray" vision, you are unable to see through the top most animation layer to notice the other animations being drawn underneath.  (This is by concept only of course, the system does not literally have the layers stacked on top of each other)

I would recommend changing your code so that you are calling your animation only once,  and take it out of the update cycle as well.

A good rule I like to live by is this:

> If change does not happen every frame, then do not include code dealing with it in the update function

This means remove time wasting if then checks like `if v.dx > abs(v.dy)` because do not need to check every frame if `v.dx` > `v.dy`,  we just need to check at the time `dx` or `dy` changes.

In your case, this happens during the `touchedMoved` event.

After you change v in this function,  do the code you have in your update function to run the animation.

of course,  you also need to remove the other moving actions so that you are not doubling up on actions.

Your code should look something like this:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    enum Direction
    {
       case none
       case up
       case down
       case left
       case right
    }
    var charDir = Direction.none
    var v = CGVector()

    var xJoystickDelta = CGFloat()
    var yJoystickDelta = CGFloat()

    var UINode = SKNode()
    var WorldNode = SKNode()

    var character = Character()

    var DPad = SKSpriteNode()
    var thumbNode = SKSpriteNode()

    var isTracking:Bool = false

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        DPad = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "base"))
        DPad.size = CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)
        DPad.position = CGPoint(x: -200, y: -100)
        DPad.zPosition = 3
        UINode.addChild(DPad)

        thumbNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "stick"))
        thumbNode.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
        thumbNode.position = CGPoint(x: -200, y: -100)
        thumbNode.zPosition = 4
        UINode.addChild(thumbNode)

        self.addChild(UINode)
        self.addChild(character)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            if isTracking == false && DPad.contains(location) {
                isTracking = true
            }
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            let location: CGPoint = touch.location(in: self)
            if isTracking == true {

                v = CGVector(dx: location.x - DPad.position.x, dy: location.y - DPad.position.y)
                var newDirection = Direction.none
                if v.dx > abs(v.dy) {
                  // right
                  newDirection = .right
                } else if v.dx < -abs(v.dy) {
                  // left
                  newDirection = .left
                } else if v.dy > 0 {
                // up
                  newDirection = .up
                } else if v.dy < 0 {
                // down
                  newDirection = .down
                }                    
                if charDir != newDirection
                {
                  charDir = newDirection
                  character.removeAllActions()
                  switch charDir{
                    case .right: character.walkEast()
                    case .left:  character.walkWest()
                    case .up:    character.walkNorth()
                    case .down:  character.walkSouth()
                    default: break
                  }
                }
                let angle = atan2(v.dy, v.dx)
                let deg = angle * CGFloat(180 / Double.pi)

                let Length:CGFloat = DPad.frame.size.height / 2
                let xDist: CGFloat = sin(angle - 1.57079633) * Length
                let yDist: CGFloat = cos(angle - 1.57079633) * Length

                xJoystickDelta = location.x - DPad.position.x
                yJoystickDelta = location.y - DPad.position.y

                if DPad.contains(location) {
                    thumbNode.position = location
                } else {
                    thumbNode.position = CGPoint(x: DPad.position.x - xDist, y: DPad.position.y + yDist)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        isTracking = false
        thumbNode.run(SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: -200, y: -100), duration: 0.01))
        xJoystickDelta = 0
        yJoystickDelta = 0
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

    }
}
```

If your character has other actions going on it, you may want to consider assigning a key to your animation instead.

Comment: Very nice. A simple, descriptive answer. I know (by the books) that I shouldn't use the update method unless absolutely necessary, but it never occurred to me. I was rushing through this trying to figure out a quick prototype. Thanks for your help!